# asp.net entity framework Contains Character problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, frameworks, entity

asp.net entity framework Contains Character problem

Table
ciğer
cikolata
vs.vs.vs.

```
public IEnumerable<Kaloriler> KaloriAra(string gelen)
{
    try
    {
        return dbKaloriler.GetAll().Where(x => x.KaloriDurumu == 1 && x.Aktivite == 0 && x.KaloriAdi.Contains(gelen)).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

How to find if the incoming data is "ciger"

data = ciger, cikolata, seker vs.
Contains : ciger = ciğer and cikolata = çikolata and şeker = seker

Comment: Man what is this Table ciğer cikolata vs.vs.vs. ??

Comment: My sql database table data "ciğer"

return dbKaloriler.GetAll().Where(x => x.KaloriDurumu == 1 && x.Aktivite == 0 && x.KaloriAdi.Contains(gelen)).ToList()

incoming data ciger return null problems

Comment: Please edit the question and explain a lot more clearly what you are having problems with, what errors you have etc. As it is currently there is no possibility anyone could know what is going on. See the Help section on how to ask.

Comment: Hello Sami,
To Sql: Select TOP 5 * From Kaloriler Where KaloriAdi Like '%çikolata%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI
how entity framework?  "COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI"

Answer (score 0):

You should have strings for English and Turkish characters. You can replace(it may be two-sided replacement from tr to en or from en to tr) the input string with possible letters. This block worked for me after the comment.

```
YourModalName yourDbModelInstance = new YourModalName();
var result = yourDbModelInstance.YourTable.Where(x => x.YourColumn.Contains(englishCriteria) || x.YourColumn.Contains(turkishCriteria));
```